# Why is the length that gets passed to my character device greater than the read length of the syscall?

Tags: c++, linux-device-driver

I have been testing my character device which I would like to have output a single character using the following:

```cpp
int main() // c++ program
{
    while (true)
    {   
        char tmp = 'x';
        std::ifstream ms_fd;
        ms_fd.open(device_path, std::ios::binary);
        ms_fd.read(&tmp, 1);
        std::cout << "val: " << tmp << std::endl;

        ms_fd.read(&tmp, 1);
        assert(ms_fd.eof());
        ms_fd.close();
        sleep(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The read calls I'm using are only ever for a single character.  But in my device driver read function, I am receiving reads of length 8191

the logs:

```bash
[  204.738324] READDRIVE:  reading len: [8191]  offset: [0]
[  204.738590] READDRIVE:  reading len: [8191]  offset: [1]
[  206.739116] READDRIVE:  reading len: [8191]  offset: [0]
[  206.739235] READDRIVE:  reading len: [8191]  offset: [1]
```

the read function is:

```c
static ssize_t pir_ms_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
    pr_info("READDRIVE:  reading len: [%d]  offset: [%d]\n", len, *off);
    ssize_t retval;
    if (*off > 0)
    {
        retval = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        put_user(buf_state, buf);
        retval = 1;
        *off+=1;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

why aren't the reads passed the argument `ssize_t len = 1`?

Comment: `ifstream.read()` is not a system call. It is a library call, from a library that does buffering. The library is calling your driver with its internal buffer size.

Comment: See https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/device_drivers.html

Comment: You should [disable the buffering on ifstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757804/ifstream-unbuffered-read-and-no-read-ahead-caching)

Answer (score 3):

`len` is not how much bytes a user application has requested. This is a buffer size, and you can read up to `len` bytes at once, the actually filled data size is returned from the function.

If you return 2 bytes, the second user call to `ms_fd.read(&tmp, 1);` will not call `pir_ms_read()`, the buffered data will be returned to a user application.

Comment: So buf in this case is a buffer managed by the ifstream class? And It attempts to retrieve 8191 bytes to reduce subsequent system calls (for performance reasons?)

Comment: Possibly yes, but 8191 is weird, the default `BUFSIZ` is 8192. Maybe 1 is reserved for the 0 terminator.

Comment: @273K I guess 1 position is being reserved as a sentinel in the circular buffer, which is quite a common way to implement circular buffers (although there are ways to implement them without a sentinel).