# How can I (cleanly!) subclass std::stringstream for a customization?

Tags: c++, string, stream

I have a logging class with a std::stringstream member.  I use it's output << overloading to get a nice easy means for catching all the data types std::stringstream gives me for free.

Here's the problem.  After sending data into the stream, I want an easy way to flush it automatically to my destination (which is variable/dynamic in nature).

`std::ostream` will "auto flush" if you send an `endl` down it.  That's and acceptable solution I would duplicate.

How can I implement that myself? Note that I don't want to override every `operator<<()` overload in `std::stringstream`!

Comment: Can't you just call `stream.flush()` after you add data to the stream?

Comment: _"Note that I don't want to override every << overload in std::stringstream!"_ Use a template overload like `std::stringstream` does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605233/how-to-disable-buffering-on-a-stream

Comment: How is that a dupp?

Comment: @Captain That's a bit far fetched.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Because his primary goal is to avoid buffering and output the string as early as possible. The linked dupe addresses that.

Comment: You might just need to overload the types that you need.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I read it as they want to enable auto flushing, not that they want to stop it.

Comment: @Captain Well, let's 1st ask how OP actually subclassed, and then discuss what entry points can be overridden for a `std::ostream`

Comment: How about you just have the `stringstream` as a member and define your own `operator <<(T &&t)` that `forward`s it to the `stringstream` and then `flush`es?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @Thomas ^^ Exactly that's what's missing here!

Comment: @nwp, thanks a template I suppose

Comment: I'm tempted to answer that this problem can be solved with an overridden [`std::basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf), rather than inheriting `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: First.  I cannot just use stream.flush().  That will do nothing for my use case.  The stream is just a place to store the data.  I then do various things with it...

Comment: The answer from nwp is interesting, but I'm not sure that will be clean.  In order to use class "T", I have to then declare what I'm sending into the steam all the time with an <SomeType> addition, no?

Comment: It takes a lot work to post the code.  I'm not looking to post piles and piles of proprietary code, which is mostly filled with irrelevant parts to it.  I would have to create a an example.  There's nothing meaningful anyway to gain from that.  I have a streamstream member and an accessor to it. I use what the class gives me for feed to free data into it.  Then, I get at the data via the stream.str() function.

Comment: I'm going to give the answer from Anon Mail a shot...

Comment: @BuvinJ _" I'm not looking to post piles and piles of proprietary code, which is mostly filled with irrelevant parts to it."_ That's why you're required to work down your problem to a [MCVE] here.

Comment: Thankfully, Anon Mail understood my needs exactly and rapidly posted a solution without me having to go through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a similar thing.  What I do is use an unnamed class instance to consume the output and put the flushing in the destructor.  Something like this:

```
int i = 0;
MyClass() << "This is a log message containing an int: " << i;
// here, the class destructs and does whatever you need to do to flush the stream
```

Comment: Operator overloading is done how exactly?

Comment: Hmm.  This is very interesting!  Should I just subclass std::stringstream then, and override nothing but its destructor?

Comment: @BuvinJ you could.  But in my case there were other things I needed the class to do so I just made the stringstream a member.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just used a single template member function to implement operator<< which then just called the stringstream method.

Comment: Brilliant solution.  This could be applicable for so many purposes!  You made my day!

Comment: I use that approach for message builder classes for logging and for throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subclassing `std::stringstream`, it's prefered to use composition (see [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)).

With this, your class would look like this:

```
class Log{

    std::stringstream _stream;

    [...] // Constructor and other class logic

    public:
    Log& operator<<(string s){
        _stream << s << endl;
        return *this;
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks.  I already have it as a member though, and my Log class is not what I << the data into.  I send data directly to the member via an accessor.  Ignoring that, your solution would force me to overload every version of the stringstream << function.  That negates the entire purpose of using it!  All I want it for is those dozens of "free" functions.